# How do I have to structure a PHP file internally to deliver the source URL of a video

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page with a video the uses something like this:

```
<video>
  <source src="http://example.com/video1.mp4">
</video>
```

I want to hide the source url.

So I can write a script that uses a token and retrieves the real URL from the database, making the URL like

```
http://example.com/video.php?token=A982134DF345e
```

but I am not seeing how can I use that as the video source URL.

Obviously I know that this will not work...

```
<video>
  <source src="http://example.com/video.php?token=A982134DF345e">
</video>
```

I want the video page to autoplay the video as it loads but never to reveal the real URL of that video.

The token will be made void after one play, so if the user wants to see the video again, the system will retrieve a new token.

How should this be done?

Comment: Your `video.php` script can use [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fpassthru()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) to send the contents of any file, including a video file. As for creating validating, and expiring the token, there are millions of ways of doing this. Ultimately the server needs to keep a database of valid tokens and you need a way of adding, removing, and validating them.

Comment: your idea is brilliant, put me on the write track and now I have the problem solved. Please make it an answer, so I can accept. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've posted my answer. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `video.php` needs to first send the proper MIME header, e.g. `video/mp4` or `video/mpeg`. Then it can use [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fpassthru()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) to send the contents of the video file.

As for creating validating, and expiring the token, there are many ways to do this. Ultimately the server needs to keep a database of valid tokens and you need a way of adding, removing, and validating them. So your `video.php` script may ultimately look a lot like this:

```
if ( validate_and_expire_token( $_REQUEST[ 'token' ] ) ) {
  header( 'Content-type: video/mp4' ); // Possibly video/mpeg
  if ( $fp = fopen( 'video1.mp4', 'rb' ) ) {
    fpassthru( $fp );
  }
}
```

Where `validate_and_expire_token()` is code you'll have to write that returns `TRUE` if the given `$token` is valid (first invalidating it so it can't be used again), `FALSE` otherwise.

Comment: Also keep in mind that I'm not checking for or handling cases where `fopen()` or `fpassthru()` fail. Additional logic to handle those cases is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Your link with token must return proper MIME headers for video such as `video/webm`, `video/ogg` or `video/mpeg`. This will allow browser to recognise properly application handler (of course, browser must first support codec for such a MIME type). Currently your original video with `video.mp4` will play in browser by recognizing file extension (mp4). If you supply common PHP link then browser will attempt to detect MIME headers.

```
header("Content-type:video/mpeg");
```

See valid video [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

The token validity is irrelevant to your question (I understand you are actually asking how to use PHP link to play properly video).